# Current state of development using Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework

Currently we are in process of building a Slack bot using Microsoft BotFramework but there is so much confusion around development and what is actively supported that it is turning out to be a roadblock one after the other.

- Firstly, there is [Choose the right chatbot solution for your use case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- Then, [The future of bot building](https://powervirtualagents.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-future-of-bot-building/)

Looking at the above, and since we have dotnet developers, we decided to continue with [dotnet SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet)

Now, there is a separate Slack adapter supported by the community [botbuilder-community-dotnet](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet). We had to use this because we wanted some features that were not supported by Azure Slack channel *(e.g. BlockKit messages)*.
There are a lot of issues with this library which is not actively developed and lacks samples.

I have fixed a few and created PRs for them

- [Added function to convert SigninCard to BlockKit](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/539)
- [Changed AzureAdAuthentication documentation to refer correct variable](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/537)

I have raised an issue as well

- https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/540

So my question is what is the latest approach to develop using Microsoft BotFramework with Slack so that we can use BlockKit, reply as a thread, etc., and has active community support?

Comment: If you're voting to close this question, please also suggest a right forum to ask this.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/

Comment: The second article you posted to "The future of bit building" looks very stale (2021). Maybe read this for a different perspective https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-build-chatgpt-slack-bot/

Comment: Thank you for the link, @Nick.McDermaid. We will have to evaluate Zapier to check if it allows all the functionalities that we require like block kit messages and replying in a thread and if it is flexible enough to work with multiple channels like botframework.

Comment: @Martheen, thank you. [Here is the question on softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87649/current-state-of-development-using-microsoft-botframework)

Comment: Are you still needing help on this? If so, it is possible to send a BlockKit using the C# SDK without relying on the community adapter. I have done this using the JS SDK and it should be equally possible using C#. Let me know if you're interested and, if so, I'll post my JS solution (I'm not strong in C#). It's not overly complicated so replicating the design in C# shouldn't be overly difficult.

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg, sure, thanks. While it may not directly answer the question, your answer may give me an alternative. At this point, I am willing to take in any input as it looks like Microsoft and DotNet community has wholly given up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this JavaScript solution with the OP's blessing. Also, this is a stripped down implementation from my own bot meant primarily as a demonstration. As-is, it doesn't do much other than send the block kit via a single waterfall step.

First, in generateWelcome.js, I make a POST request to a webhook I generated in my Slack app located under **Incoming Webhooks**. This request also includes the Slack app's Bot User OAuth Token, located under **OAuth & Permissions**, in the `Authorization` header. The body contains the stringified JSON of my block kit. Unfortunately, I don't remember which scopes are necessary as I have more than a few enabled (for testing). So, you may need to research this little bit out.

**generateSlackWelcome.js**

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = async (context) => {
  const { membersAdded } = context.activity;

  for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
    if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
      await fetch(
        'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Host: 'hooks.slack.com',
            Accept: '*/*',
            Authorization: 'Bearer xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXppq3e',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            text: 'Now back in stock! :tada:',
            attachments: [
              {
                title: 'The Further Adventures of Slackbot',
                author_name: 'Stanford S. Strickland',
                author_icon: 'https://api.slack.com/img/api/homepage_custom_integrations-2x.png',
                image_url: 'http://i.imgur.com/OJkaVOI.jpg?1',
              },
              {
                fields: [
                  {
                    title: 'Volume',
                    value: '1',
                    short: true,
                  },
                  {
                    title: 'Issue',
                    value: '3',
                    short: true,
                  },
                ],
              },
              {
                title: 'Synopsis',
                text: 'After Johnny pushed exciting changes to a devious new branch back in Issue 1, Slackbot notifies Marco about an unexpected deploy...',
              },
              {
                fallback: 'Would you recommend it to customers?',
                title: 'Would you recommend it to customers?',
                callback_id: 'comic_1234_xyz',
                color: '#3AA3E3',
                attachment_type: 'default',
                actions: [
                  {
                    name: 'recommend',
                    text: 'Recommend',
                    type: 'button',
                    value: 'recommend',
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'no',
                    text: 'No',
                    type: 'button',
                    value: 'bad',
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          }),
        }
      ).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return;
        throw new Error(res.statusText);
      });
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

In slackDialog.js, I import the exported function from generateSlackWelcome.js as `slackWelcome`. I construct the dialog, as usual, and call `slackWelcome` in a waterfall step which then posts the block kit message to the Slack channel (which is also specified) via the webhook.

**slackDialog.js**

```js
const { ComponentDialog, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');

const slackWelcome = require('./resources/scripts/slackWelcome');

const SLACK_DIALOG = 'slackDialog';

class SlackDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);

    this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(SLACK_DIALOG, [
        this.slackStep.bind(this),
      ]));

    this.initialDialogId = SLACK_DIALOG;
  }

  async slackStep(stepContext) {
    const { context: { activity: { channelId } } = stepContext;

    if (channelId === 'slack') {
      return await slackWelcome(stepContext);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope of help!